# Parsing raw text in splunk between a word pattern

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need to extract the text from raw text in   Splunk query

Here is a small portion of the _raw logs that I need to extract =>

```
com.abc.xyz.service.exception.MY ERROR: null
```

"MY ERROR" can be anything, there are 40 different errors that I see in the logs, but always in the same format.

How can I extract error using rex and _raw?

Comment: Hello Nisheeth,


What does "always in the same format" mean?


1) Is it always after "com.abc.xyz.service.exception."  ? Is a kind of com.???.???.service.exception the pattern? And definitely different from other messages you are not interested in?

2) Always with ": " before the value?

3) Is the value ending with a new line?


Trying to clarify a little bit.

Comment: `| rex "com.abc.xyz.service.exception.(?<error>.*): null"`

Comment: Hi, 
Somewhere in the splunk logs, there will be in one of the following examples:
com.abc.xyz.service.exception.Unable to connect to Database: null 
com.abc.xyz.service.exception.Bad Gateway: null
com.abc.xyz.service.exception.Registered endpoint failed to handle the request: null

Answer (score 2):

*IF* your pattern is *actually* in the format of

```
com.abc.xyz.service.exception.MY ERROR: null
```

And you want whatever is between the last dot and the colon, [then this works](https://regex101.com/r/WP2ShL/1):

```
| rex field=_raw "\.(?<errcode>[\w\s]+)\:"
```